# In CSS, is "table" in "table td { ... }" really needed? Can "td" occur not within a table?

Tags: html, css

I think a `td` not within a `table` probably won't validate as HTML or XHTML and therefore the behavior is not well defined, so there probably is no practical use of `td` without `table`.

So in CSS, the `table` in

```
table td { padding: 0 2em }
```

is really not need, as `td` must be inside a `table`, isn't it true?

(**Update:** `table td` occurs such as in Sass, where programmers probably write style such as

```
table:
  background: #fff
  td:
    border: 1px solid #000
```

and it will get compiled to `table td` for the `td` part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not needed.
This, however, is why people do it:

```
table#tps_report td{ padding: 0 2em }
```

And then table is left as an orphan when it has no id purely out of habit. I am sure it also makes the task easier for the CSS+DOM parser.

Comment: It isn't less work - it's more work (than just `td`). See: http://www.css-101.org/descendant-selector/go_fetch_yourself.php

Comment: Only if the right-most selector is an id selector. The id fetch takes the parser much less time than finding all tables, then all the td descendants, then the particular id. However, in a page with 10 tables, you are better off specifying which table is in question.

Comment: I disagree - remember, browsers parse selectors right to left. With `td`, all the `td` tags are found; done. With `table#tps_report td`, all the `td` tags are found, *then* there's the extra work of checking they're inside `#tps_report` and `table`. Clearly the first selector takes less time. "Only if the right-most selector is an id selector." - what? The rightmost selector is always `td` if you want to style `td` tags.

Comment: I wasn't arguing that. I was just saying that in cases where you are looking for a specific table you ought to specify it. I was unaware of the right-to-left reading surprisingly, thank you.

Comment: less/more is not the point, CSS uses specificity, you might not want every TD to match your selector (unlike an ID), so even if the browser says "I found them all" it doesn't matter. CSS is actually asking to it look a little bit further back, mostly, unless you class everything- the site is overkill :), an ID on the right should always be unique!. The key to speed and efficiency is making the selector "fail" as quickly as possible so the browser doesn't waste time looking back unnecessarily, your e.g. could be `#tps_report>tbody>tr>td{padding: 0 2em}` to be super efficient, an ID is king

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is that `table` gives the selector higher specificity => rules in `table td` selector will always override rules in `td` selector.

Answer (score 2):

It should not be necessary.

```
td { padding: 0 2em }
```

Just using TD will be more efficient as well not only in bytes but also in the application of the CSS rules to the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah `td` can only occur within a `table` element so styling via:

```
td { padding: 0em 2em; }
```

Is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

This also applies to `form` and `list` tags (as well as others).

Typing:

```
form input { width: 50px; color:red; }
ul li { padding:5px 0; }
```

is the same as:

```
input { width: 50px; color:red; }
li { padding:5px 0; }
```